# Trashcan fatal error: no input files

Tags: scripts, c

I have to build a trashcan in shell. The trashcan has the following funktions: get(`-g`), put(`-p`) and remove from trashcan (`-r`).

So i tried to compile this (`gcc -o trashcan.sh`) but i got a `fatal error: no input files`. I'm in the right directory. I don't know whats wrong. Please help, I'm new to this.

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir("ti3_trash",S_IRWXU)

clear() {
   echo -e "Clear Trashcan? (y|n)"
   read -a
   if [[ "$a" = "n" ]] || [[ "$a" = "N" ]]; then
       exit 0
   else
       cd ~/ti3_trash && rm -rf files/*
       rm -r info/*
   fi
}

list() {
   echo -e "current contents of the Trashcan:"
   ls ~/ti3_trash/files
}

case "$1" in
   -p) mv $2 ~/ti3_trash/files 
   ;;
   -r) clear
   ;;
   -g) cd ~/ti3_trash/files && mv $2 $HOME
   ;;
   *) list
   ;;
esac
```

Comment: The error is because you are specifying an *output* file (`-o`) but no input file. But the bigger question: **why are you trying to compile a shell script with gcc**?

Comment: My question exactly @steeldriver

Answer (score 1):

you're using the wrong tool. GCC is to compile C code. you are making bash code which interpreted at runtime. all you need to do is give it executable permission. take a look at the man page for chmod `man chmod` and decide what permissions you want it to have. or just run `chmod 711 [your file name]`